# C# Inserting into sql table with case statement

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I'am creating an `InsertTable` method into `AigsAuthorityLayer` table but there is some event where depends on the authority scope. If `scope is ==` to system, it will be equals to 1, when `scope is ==` to sharing, the value of Group Id is `GroupId = aigsDB.GetDefGroup(Convert.ToString(context.Session["GroupID"])).Rows[0]["lSharingGid"].ToString();` and if it is `scope == to group`, it will be

```
authority = aigsDB.GetDefGroupUser(Convert.ToString(context.Session["UserId"].ToString()));
```

For editFlg, if it is equals to one, it will return true and if not, false

```
CommonMethod.CheckLogin();
        string sqlWord = CommonDB.CreateSqlString("AigsAuthorityLayer", "*", "", "", "");
        context = HttpContext.Current;

        CommonDB comDB = new CommonDB(connection);     

        try

        {
            string sql = "INSERT INTO AigsAuthorityLayer (lGid, LayerNo, lAuthority, IEditFlg ) VALUES('{0}',{1}, {2},{3}')";
            sql = sql.Replace("{0}", GroupId);
            sql = sql.Replace("{1}", layerName.ToString());
            sql = sql.Replace("{2}", authority.ToString());
            sql = sql.Replace("{3}", editFlg.ToString());
            comDB.Open();
            comDB.AddNewRecord(sql);               

            {

            comDB.Close();
            comDB = null;
        }
            GroupId = "-1";
            authority = "-1";

            if (scope == "system")
            {
                return GroupId;
            }
            else if (scope == "sharing")
            {
                GroupId = aigsDB.GetDefGroup(Convert.ToString(context.Session["GroupID"])).Rows[0]["lSharingGid"].ToString();
            }
            else if (scope == "group")
            {
                authority = aigsDB.GetDefGroupUser(Convert.ToString(context.Session["UserId"].ToString()));
            }
            return true;
        }
           catch (Exception e)
         {
            throw logger.Error("InsertAigsAuthorityLayer", e);
         }
        finally
        {

            if (editFlg == "1")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
            comDB.Close();
            comDB = null;
    }
```

}

My problem is, I don't know if I got it right :( Anyone know if this code is correct or not? thanks

Comment: Why don't you using [parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) instead of string replace? Your question seems little bit unclear by the way.

Comment: @SonerGönül has a massive point.  You're completely open to Injection and should change to parameterised queries

Comment: I have no idea how to do that sorry @SonerGönül this is just the first time ill be working with c#. But will my code work?

Comment: @JonBellamy This is how they do the codes here so I just used their method on mine

Comment: You could search SO for parameterized queries or just Google. Time to update "them" on "how they do the codes here" by being the first one to do it the right (=safe) way :-)

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar couldn't put it better myself. Lyn, be the first one to change things for the better.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why technically it might not work but you should always test your own code.  However there are several improvements that could be made.

Firstly, you should use parameterised queries to protect against SQL Injection.  Secondly, consider c# using statements to help deal with auto-disposing of objects when complete.  For example:

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("<connection string here>")
{
    string cmdString = "INSERT INTO AigsAuthorityLayer (lGid, LayerNo, lAuthority, IEditFlg ) VALUES(@lGid, @layerNo, @lAuthority, @lEditFlag)";
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdString, conn)
    {

        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

        SqlParameterCollection p = cmd.Parameters;

        // Build a parameter for each of @lGid, @layerNo, @lAuthority, @lEditFlag
        SqlParameter p1 = p.AddWithValue("@lGid", GroupId);
        p1.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int; // Int assumed here

        // Repeat for other parameters
        ...

        // Run query as needed
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Or appropriate method

    }
}
```

By utilising the `using` statements, regardless of success or error the `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` objects will be auto-disposed once complete and all resources released.  Secondly, by using SqlParameters, you protect against Sql Injection.  In your current method, someone could enter (for example) a ";" followed by a "DELETE FROM" or "DROP TABLE" command in one of your values to cause all sorts of problems.

Lastly, the above can be wrapped in a try...catch if you want to capture an error, and do something with / about it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I suggest you update the parameter line as `p.AddWithValue("@lGid", GroupId)` so it can't be mixed up with the column name when reading.

Comment: Crap, simple typo.  Thank you @ThorstenDittmar

Comment: Thanks guys :) I will update my codes now :) hope everything works @JonBellamy